# Use Command key only to launch Spotlight?

Tags: macos, mac, hotkeys, spotlight

I've recently switched to MacOS because my employer decided to give me a shiny new MacBook Pro 14 inch (2021), with which in general I'm quite happy. However, one thing keeps bugging me. I'm a relative power user and very comfortable on both Linux (Ubuntu and others) and Windows. On both these OSes, the primary (basically only) way I launch apps is by hitting the "Super" a.k.a. "Windows" key once, start typing what I want to launch, and as soon as there is a unique match I hit Return to launch that app.

The obvious MacOS analogue is Spotlight. *However* this requires Command + Space to launch, which is inconvenient since it's two keystrokes. I may have been able to get used to this, if I would have been able to strike both Command and Space at the same time, but unfortunately the OS only registers it as a hotkey if I press Command first, wait a very tiny moment (at least 100 ms I would guess), and only then press Space. This is too slow to be convenient for me.

Is there any way to configure **Command by itself as a hotkey for Spotlight**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to implement this! Using BetterTouchTool I used *not* a separate keyboard shortcut (that won't work and Cmd always only registers as a modifier) but using a 'Key Sequence'. There I could record `Cmd-Down` - `Cmd-Up` as a sequence to launch Spotlight. Just like I wanted. It does not interfere with general usage of Cmd, since that exact sequence only happens with a single press of Cmd. Problem solved!

Comment: Great tip! Although I can't seem to find Spotlight in the list of apps that I can launch, could you please explain how you activate Spotlight?

Comment: @IgorTiulkanov bind 'Cmd+Space' ("send keyboard shortcut" or so) as the action, that will in turn trigger Spotlight (if your OS is configured that way, which I think it is by default).

Answer (score 2):

Space only needs to be second by *nanoseconds*, so short you can't hear the two keys as separate events. If I hit the pair at once with my thumb, it registers, just so long as I don't lead with Space.

It's *possible* using something like [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), to use just Cmd as a trigger - but you'll have to introduce some other compensator, such as it must wait for key up before registering that you want Spotlight rather than it still waiting for any other Cmd key combo.

I'd consider learning to use it the way it was intended, rather than trying to override what is such a comprehensive global modifier key.
Cmd is more akin to Ctrl on a PC, it is nothing like an equivalent of the Windows key.